# Pull an image from AzureCR using docker task in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am trying to pull a docker image from an Azure CR connected via service connection.
I was following this guideline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops#overview

And although the "pull" is not mentioned in the docs the command was executed in the pipeline. But the image was tried to be pulled from dockerhub and not via the configured service connection.

Can this be fixed somehow? I do not want to expose the AzureCR url in the pull command but want to use the service connection instead.

I am using the task like this

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Pull image
  inputs:
    command: pull
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection
    arguments: <imagename>:<tag>
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your Docker task details?

Comment: I extended the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Login to registry
  inputs: 
    command: login
    containerRegistry: $(registry) # variable with Service Connection name
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Pulling docker image
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    # docker_registry_name - name of the private repository
    script: |
      docker pull $(docker_registry_name)/$(image_name):$(tag)
```

I had to add `Docker@2` and `login`. Before that I had an error saying `no basic auth credentials`.

Answer (score 2):

Without any extensions you can do:

```
- task: Docker@1
  displayName: "docker pull from ACR"
  inputs:
    azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '<service connection>'
    azureContainerRegistry: <your ACR name>.azurecr.io
    command: pull
    arguments: '<your ACR name>.azurecr.io/<path to your image>:<version>'
```

For other Docker tasks , like building and pushing, the ACR name is taken from container registry variable. Here I had to be explicit about the ACR name in `arguments`. Maybe the same would work for `Docker@2`.

Unfortunately I can only find documentation for [Docker@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops).

Comment: But "pull" is not in the command options – see https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/bd84d4aabd513d2468c2522be48ac0b544fc3d99/Tasks/DockerV1/task.json#L91.

Comment: @malthe yes... but it turns out that the drop-down list is not complete and you can [edit the command](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13846). Just really poorly documented IMO...

Comment: But the primary benefit of the built-in commands is that you don't have to fill in `azureContainerRegistry` (i.e., ACR name).

Comment: Good point :) but the OP would like to pull from ACR. You could login and pull in a script task or do what I propose in a single step. Extending Docker@2 to include pull would be the nicest solution though, I agree.

Comment: Even with the use of a script task it is not obvious how to extract the ACR name. At least I have tried and failed.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use `Pull images from ACR` task to pull an image from AzureCR.

[image]

[image]

In yaml pipeline:

[image]

[image]

```
- task: azure container registry@1
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceNameARM: 'xxx'
    ResourceGroupName: 'xxx'
    Azurecontainerregistry: 'xxx'
    dockerimages: 'xxx'
```

Comment: Is this possible in the yml file too? What is the syntax of the task in the pipeline yml file?

Comment: Yes, it is also applicable in yaml pipeline, you can add it from tasks, please view my update.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. I did not find any doc about that task so I do not know which details are required to use it. Can you share a link?

Comment: This is an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SiddharthKalai.ACR&ssr=false#overview) need to be installed. :)

Comment: Unfortunately our company policy does not allow to install extensions that are not coming from MS or the MS DevLabs. Nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here a slightly adapted version for docker task v2:

```
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Docker pull
      inputs:
        command: pull
        containerRegistry: <your-service-connection>
        arguments: <your-repository>.azurecr.io/<your-image>:<your-tag>
```

Comment: I just wonder why `pull` is not a valid option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml